# Can't unpause SKScene after adding a label

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skscene

I can pause and unpause the SKScene with a pause button(SKSpriteNode) and a simple method.

```
-(void) pauseGame {

    SKView *view = (SKView *) self.view;

    if(!view.paused){
        view.paused = YES;

    }else{
        view.paused = NO;
        [pauseLabel removeFromParent];
    }    
}
```

And call it in the touchesBegan Method

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
    SKNode *node = [self nodeAtPoint:location];

    // If game is paused allow the button to be touched
    if (isGamePaused == NO) {


        //if pause button touched, pause the game
        if (node == pauseButton) {

            [self pauseGame];

        }
    }
}
```

This way works fine. I can push the button to pause the game and push it again to unpause the game. However, I want to give the user a way to know the game is paused other then the screen be frozen, so I tried this:

I create this SKLabel.

```
-(void) addPauseLabel {

    // Creating label
    pauseLabel = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:universalFont];
    pauseLabel.text = @"Game is Paused";
    pauseLabel.fontSize = 42;
    pauseLabel.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width/2, self.frame.size.height/2 + 60);
    pauseLabel.zPosition = 6;

    [self addChild:pauseLabel];
}
```

Then I created a sequence in which I add the label then pause the game

```
-(void) pauseSequence{

    SKAction *pauseSequence = [SKAction sequence:@[
                                                   [SKAction performSelector:@selector(addPauseLabel) onTarget:self],
                                                   [SKAction performSelector:@selector(pauseGame) onTarget:self],
                                                   ]];
    [self runAction:pauseSequence];

}
```

And finally, in the touchesBegan method, I call [self pauseSquence]; at the end instead of [self pauseGame];

When I push the pause button the label is added and the game is pauseed, but pushing the button again to unpuase the game doesn't do anything. Why is that? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't run an action while the view is paused, so you should call `[self pauseSequence]` if the view is not paused and `[self pauseGame]` if the view is paused.

In the `touchesBegan` method

```
if (!self.view.paused) {
    // Add label and pause
    [self pauseSequence];
}
else {
    // Resume game
    [self pauseGame];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The most likely reason your unpause button doesn't work is that after you pause, no touches can be detected. You are essentially locking yourself out of the scene, meaning the scene can't do work to unpause itself.

The generally accepted way to pause a SpriteKit game is to not pause the scene, but to create multiple nodes. One node will contain your gameplay (the "Game Layer") and the other will contain pause elements (the "Pause Layer"). When your scene detects the pause button has been pressed, set everything in the Game Layer to paused, then bring up your Pause Layer. When the resume button is pressed, hide the Pause Layer and unpause the Game Layer.

Comment: Touches aren't disabled when the view is paused, so a pause layer is not required.

Comment: The pause/unpause function work perfectly. However, when I try to pause, add label and then unpause, I cannot unpause.

Answer (score 0):

You should know that the sequence serves no purpose here. It's best to just call:

```
[self addPauseLabel];
[self pauseGame];
```

Since that's the main change it's possible that the odd and unnecessary use of a sequence causes this behavior.

Comment: The label won't be added to the scene if you replace the sequence with the above code.

Comment: It will, but perhaps the view getting paused immediately afterwards will not update (render) the scene?

Comment: I tried this and yes, the label is added, but the scene is paused before the label can be rendered and only appears after unpausing scene.